# Akeneo: Product list in product edit page

Tags: php, akeneo

Is it possible in Akeneo to get select-box with all other products in product add/edit page?

My problem is:
I need to add to products a new attribute “grouped product” (yes/no). If this attribute is set to “yes” – I need to show multiselect-box with other products, in which this attribute also set to “yes”.

Is it possible to do this by existing methods? And if not – I will be grateful for any suggestions.

UPD: I’ll try to describe the example.

Let’s imagine I have some products:
1) Mobile phone “X” (attribute “grouped product” – no)
2) Cover for mobile phone “X” (attribute “grouped product” – yes)
3) Screen protector film for mobile phone “X” (attribute “grouped product” – yes)
4) Battery for mobile phone “X” (attribute “grouped product” – no)

When I go to edit **mobile phone “X”** and change attribute “grouped product” to “yes” – will appear select-tag with other products, saved as “grouped product” (in my example there are two options in this select-tag – **cover for mobile phone “X”** and **screen protector film for mobile phone “X”**). I can select some of this options (for example – **cover for mobile phone “X”**) and save it.

In result I want to have product **mobile phone “X”** with attached product **cover for mobile phone “X”** to sell them as a single product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to acheive is called product associations. You can already do that natively in Akeneo PIM and export them as a pack.

You can also do a custom export to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Julien! But product associations are actually use for cross-selling and up-selling. I need something like that but I also need to change some parameters in attached product, for example, price - but only price for attachment (when I attach **cover for mobile phone "X"** and change it's price to new - I want that in _attached product_ **cover for mobile phone "X"** was **new** price, and in _product_ **cover for mobile phone "X"** was it's **old** price).

Comment: In the demo fixtures we created association type for cross selling and up selling but you can also create your own association type. Also you can create custom logic to ensure those custom rules. You could also do these kind of custom rules with Akeneo PIM enterprise edition natively

Comment: And one more question – is it some possible to change some parameters (like price) only in associated products? Like I described - when I associate **cover for mobile phone “X”** and change it’s price to new – I want that in _associated product_ **cover for mobile phone “X”** was new price, and in _single product_ **cover for mobile phone “X”** was it’s old price. Maybe this opportunity is present in Enterprise Edition?